# How can I start the calendar week in ng bootstrap Datepicker from Sunday instead of Monday?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, ngb-datepicker

I want to set the ngbDatepicker to begin the week on Sunday instead of the default day Monday.

I am trying to use **weekStartsOn="0"** but it has no effect.
This is my html code

`<input ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" class="form-control" [minDate]="minDate" [maxDate]="maxDate" [markDisabled]="isDisabled" weekStartsOn="0">`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve that by passing in `7` to the `firstDayOfWeek` input property.

E.g.

```html
<input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" name="dp" 
    [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" firstDayOfWeek="7">
```

[image]

If you need to further configure/tweak your datepicker, you can take a look at `ng-bootstrap` datepicker component's full API here: [Ng-Bootstrap Datepicker API](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#NgbDatepicker).

Here's a forked stackblitz to show that it works: [Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-apjjfb?file=app/datepicker-popup.html).

Comment: Thank you, I also see that **firstDayOfWeek="0"** works