# Start the week on Sunday instead of Monday with ngx-bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular, date, calendar, ngx-bootstrap, dayofweek

According to international standard ISO 8601, Monday is the first day of the week. However, in the Gregorian calendar currently used in most countries, Sunday is considered the beginning of the week.

The ngx-bootstrap `datepicker` enables the developer to [define the first day of the week through the use of locales](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/old/6.1.0/#/datepicker#locales). For example, English Language has "en" locale which starts the week on Sunday and also "en-gb" locale that starts the week on Monday. The French Language however only has a single locale "fr" that starts the week on Monday.

With the Material Design `MatDatePicker` the developer can override a method `getFirstDayOfWeek` of the class `NativeDateAdapter` to [indicate the desired first day of the week as an integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45020144/1445318), while the ng-bootstrap `ngbDatepicker` component [allows the developer to control the choice of first day of the week](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58970202/1445318) through an option on the component.

Is there a similar solution that can be used to set the first day of the week to Sunday for the French language/locale using the ngx-bootstrap `datepicker` component?